# Activiating integrated webcam on Toshiba Chromebook

Tags: video, skype, webcam, chromebook, camera

We are having trouble activating the Chicony integrated web cam in a Toshiba CB30 - 102 Chromebook. It did not work with Ubuntu 14.04 and is still not working with Ubuntu 15.10 after trying many fixes:

We tried Cheese, VLC, gtkuvc video viewer and Skype but none of them work.

The error for cheese is as follows:

```
(cheese:2168): cheese-WARNING **: Could not read from resource.: gstv4l2bufferpool.c(1054): gst_v4l2_buffer_pool_poll (): /GstCameraBin:camerabin/GstWrapperCameraBinSrc:camera_source/GstBin:bin18/GstV4l2Src:video_source:
poll error 1: Invalid argument (22)


** (cheese:2168): CRITICAL **: cheese_preferences_dialog_on_source_change: assertion '_tmp2_ > ((guint) 0)' failed

(cheese:2168): cheese-CRITICAL **: cheese_camera_device_get_device_node: assertion 'CHEESE_IS_CAMERA_DEVICE (device)' failed

(cheese:2168): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_variant_new_string: assertion 'string != NULL' failed

(cheese:2168): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_settings_schema_key_type_check: assertion 'value != NULL' failed

(cheese:2168): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_variant_get_type_string: assertion 'value != NULL' failed

(cheese:2168): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_settings_set_value: key 'camera' in 'org.gnome.Cheese' expects type 's', but a GVariant of type '(null)' was given

** (cheese:2168): CRITICAL **: cheese_preferences_dialog_setup_resolutions_for_device: assertion 'device != NULL' failed
```

We also tried adding my user to the video group.

And running cheese using sudo.

And lowering the resolution.

None of this is working.

The camera model is properly identified in Cheese and other programs, as TOSHIBA Web Camera (/dev/video0). See screenshots below:

[image: Cheese error image]

[image: Cheese preferences image]

```
ls -l /dev/video*
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 0 Jan  7 11:38 /dev/video0


lsusb
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0930:021c Toshiba Corp. Atheros AR3012 Bluetooth
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 04f2:b433 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Snippet from lshw

```
*-usb:0
                   description: Video
                   product: TOSHIBA Web Camera - HD
                   vendor: Chicony Electronics Co.,Ltd.
                   physical id: 3
                   bus info: usb@1:3
                   version: 29.66
                   serial: 0001
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=uvcvideo maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
```

Comment: This may sound silly...but, does that chromebook have soft keys to turn ON/OFF webcam because ,in your case the cam is detected by the OS....Even I faced the same prob. but the final solution was fn+F*

Comment: Thanks, but I don't have a button to turn the webcam on/off, unfortunately. Any other suggestions are welcome.